# Centering Button through css?

Tags: html, css

I want to centre the submit button but when i set align to center it did not work. I seen this question was previously asked but it did not work in my case.
my css code

```html
input[type=submit] {
 width:40%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color:Black;
 font-size:16px;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
 text-align:center;
 
}
```

My whole CSS code

```html
 div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:#efcbcb;
 }
 
 
.lay{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 height:500px;
 width:600px;
 text-align:center;
 float:right;
 }
 
input[type=submit] {
 width:40%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color:Black;
 font-size:16px;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
 margin:0 auto;
 
}
.sub{
text-align:center;
 }

 
 label{
    
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 250px;
 height:40px;
  
}
    input {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    float: left;
     }
```

my form Code

```html
<div class="lay">
<p class="reg"><h1>Registration Form</h1></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<label>Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username"  value="<?php echo $username;?>" id="username"  />
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $usernameErr;?></span>
<br /><br />
<label>Password:</label> <input type="text" name="password"  value="<?php echo $password;?>" id="password"  />
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
<br /><br />
<label>Email:  </label>  <input type="text" name="email"     value="<?php echo $email;?>" id="email"     />
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
<br /><br />
<label>Contact:</label>  <input type="text" name="contact"   value="<?php echo $contact;?>" id="contact"   />
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $contactErr;?></span>
<br /><br />
<label>Facebook:</label> <input type="text" name="facebook"  value="<?php echo $facebook;?>" id="facebook"  />
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $facebookErr;?></span>
<br /><br />
<label>Cnic No:</label>  <input type="text" name="cnic"      value="<?php echo $cnic;?>" id="cnic"      />
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $cnicErr;?></span>
<br /><br />
<label>Expertise:</label><input type="text" name="expertise" value="<?php echo $expertise;?>" id="expertise" />
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $expertiseErr;?></span>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="sub"><input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" id="register" /></div>
</form>
</div>
```

my result:[image]

Comment: add `margin:0 auto;` to your CSS...

Comment: Though not supported in HTML5 you could (if that does not concern you) use the `align` property of a `div`.

Comment: @Lal still same result

Comment: can you show the code of your `form`?

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: @Script still same result wait i post my whole css code

Comment: @ravishankar plz check now

Comment: Place your button inside a `<div>` with the CSS property `text-align: center`.  That is perhaps the easiest route.

Comment: @Lal bro check it now

Comment: @Script47 bro check it now

Comment: Done thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your `input[type="submit"]` CSS:

```
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `type = "submit"` instead of `type = submit`

```
input[type="submit"] {
    width:40%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color:Black;
    font-size:16px;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;

}
```

Comment: bro it start work with      transform: translate(100%, -10%)

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/r4uLcwm6/)

You should remove your floats to make it centered. Here is the updated CSS for the submit button. I've used `float:none;`.

UPDATED CSS

```
input[type=submit] {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: Black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Read from your comments that you made it working using `transform` css. But, just to point out, the `transform` css will work only on IE 9+ and other webkit browsers.

Read more about it in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127312(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: bro it start work with transform: translate(100%, -10%)

Comment: OK great..:) Glad that it worked.. try this solution too as it works in almost all browsers..

Comment: Thanks bro okay i will it now

Comment: bro your solution also work but not at exact middle as it work with transform: translate(90%, 30%)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, edit as

```
<div class="sub">
<button class="button" type="submit" name="register"  id="register">Register</button>
</div>
```

In CSS, edit as

```
.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
}
```